# Get indices of non null scipy sparse csr matrix rows

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to get the indices of the rows of a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` that are not null.  For example:

```
A = [ 0 0 0 0 0 1
      0 0 0 0 0 0 
      1 1 0 0 0 0 ]
```

Desired output:

```
indices = [0, 2]
```

Comment: A zero is null???

Comment: By "not null" you mean "all zero"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
from scipy.sparse import find, csr_matrix
import numpy as np

A = csr_matrix(np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]))
print(A.todense())

nnz_per_row = A.getnnz(axis=1)
result = np.where(nnz_per_row > 0)[0]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0]]
[0 2]
```